# CameraStream Trait webrtc

Tags: webrtc, google-smart-home

I see on the google home document that google CameraStream webrtc currently supports 1-way (half duplex) communication. When will it support two-way intercom?

Answer (score 2):

Duplex webrtc is not yet supported by CameraStream trait, but Google is constantly monitoring feature requests on its public tracker.

You can file a request on the public tracker([here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148)), and check for more information in regards to this feature development.